# Upload de PDF por ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, file-upload

Tenho um form com varias inputs text e 1 input file (onde faço o envio de um arquivo PDF). Se eu enviar por ajax ele não faz o envio do "FILE", testei enviar sem ajax, apenas por submit, e funcionou. A questao esta mesmo no envio por ajax. Fiz algumas varias pesquisas sobre o assunto, mas não consegui solucionar. Poderiam me apontar uma solução para esse caso por favor.

Esse é o script js:

```
$("#cadastrarJob").click(function (){
var trabalho  = $("#jobTrabalho").val();
var cliente   = $("#jobCliente").val();
var valor     = $("#jobValorContrato").val();
var gastos    = $("#jobGastos").val();
var descricao = $("#jobDescricao").val();
var file      = $("#jobFile").val();

if(trabalho == '' || cliente == '' || valor == '' || gastos == '' || descricao == '' || file == ''){
    $.notify({
        message: 'Preencha todos os campos!',
        },{
        // settings
        element: 'body',
        position: null,
        type: "danger",
        placement: {
            from: "top",
            align: "center"
        }
    });
}else{
    var data = $("#formAddJob").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url  : '../conexao/addJob.php',
        data : data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success :  function(retorno){
            if(retorno.erro == 0){
                alert(retorno.mensagem);
            }
        }
    });    
}
});
```

Esse é o PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['trabalho']) && $_POST['trabalho'] != ''):

$trabalho   = (isset($_POST['trabalho'])) ? $_POST['trabalho'] : '' ;
$cliente    = (isset($_POST['cliente'])) ? $_POST['cliente'] : '' ;
$vContrato  = (isset($_POST['valor'])) ? $_POST['valor'] : '' ;
$gEstimados = (isset($_POST['gastos'])) ? $_POST['gastos'] : '' ;
$descricao  = (isset($_POST['descricao'])) ? $_POST['descricao'] : '' ;

// Pasta onde o arquivo vai ser salvo
$_UP['pasta'] = '../img/logoClientes/';
// Tamanho máximo do arquivo (em Bytes)
$_UP['tamanho'] = 1024 * 1024 * 10; // 10Mb
// Array com as extensões permitidas
$_UP['extensoes'] = array('pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'jpg');
// Renomeia o arquivo? (Se true, o arquivo será salvo como .jpg e um nome único)
$_UP['renomeia'] = false;
// Array com os tipos de erros de upload do PHP
$_UP['erros'][0] = 'Não houve erro';
$_UP['erros'][1] = 'O arquivo no upload é maior do que o limite do PHP';
$_UP['erros'][2] = 'O arquivo ultrapassa o limite de tamanho especifiado no HTML';
$_UP['erros'][3] = 'O upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente';
$_UP['erros'][4] = 'Não foi feito o upload do arquivo';
// Verifica se houve algum erro com o upload. Se sim, exibe a mensagem do erro
if ($_FILES['file']['error'] != 0) {

  die("Não foi possível fazer o upload, erro:" . $_UP['erros'][$_FILES['file']['error']]);
  exit; // Para a execução do script
}
// Caso script chegue a esse ponto, não houve erro com o upload e o PHP pode continuar
// Faz a verificação da extensão do arquivo
$arquivo = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$arr = explode('.', $arquivo);
$extensao = strtolower(end($arr));
if (array_search($extensao, $_UP['extensoes']) === false) {
  echo "Por favor, envie arquivos com as seguintes extensões: jpg, doc ou pdf";
  exit;
}
// Faz a verificação do tamanho do arquivo
if ($_UP['tamanho'] < $_FILES['file']['size']) {
  echo "O arquivo enviado é muito grande, envie arquivos de até 10Mb.";
  exit;
}
// O arquivo passou em todas as verificações, hora de tentar movê-lo para a pasta
// Primeiro verifica se deve trocar o nome do arquivo
if ($_UP['renomeia'] == true) {
  // Cria um nome baseado no UNIX TIMESTAMP atual e com extensão .jpg
  $nome_final = md5(time()).'.jpg';
} else {
  // Mantém o nome original do arquivo
  $nome_final = $_FILES['file']['name'];
}

// Depois verifica se é possível mover o arquivo para a pasta escolhida
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_UP['pasta'] . $nome_final)) {
  // Upload efetuado com sucesso, exibe uma mensagem e um link para o arquivo
  echo "Upload efetuado com sucesso!";
  echo '<a href="' . $_UP['pasta'] . $nome_final . '">Clique aqui para acessar o arquivo</a>';
} else {
  // Não foi possível fazer o upload, provavelmente a pasta está incorreta
  echo "Não foi possível enviar o arquivo, tente novamente";
}


    $retorno['erro']     = '0';
    $retorno['mensagem'] = 'Tem post';
    echo json_encode($retorno);
else:    
    $retorno['erro']     = '0';
    $retorno['mensagem'] = 'Não tem post';
    echo json_encode($retorno);
endif;
?>
```

> Lembrando que o codigo PHP esta funcionando perfeitamente, pois testei ele sem ajax, apenas por submit e funcionou certinho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Então para realizar o upload precisa realizar a chamada do ajax da seguinte forma

Pega o arquivo do formulário

```
 var file_data = $('#take-picture').prop('files')[0];
 var form_data = new FormData();



jqxhr = $.ajax( {
    type: 'POST',
    url  : '../conexao/addJob.php',
    data:form_data,
    processData:false, 
    contentType:false,
})
insira o código aqui
```

processData:false // impede o processamento automático que por padrão é chave valor

contentType:false // diz a requisição que não gere um cabeçalho padrão para o envio, por padrão essa configuração vem como true no jquery, isso adiciona um cabeçalho uft-8 que pode impedir o envio de arquivos

FormData //Permite anexar objetos de arquivo para solicitações XHR (solicitações Ajax)

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que o Jquery não encontra o caminho até ao ficheiro que você quer fazer upload, ou seja, se você fizer um alert ao input file você vai ver que vai dar por exemplo ***C:/fakepath/(nome_do_ficheiro.pdf)***

Penso que não seja possível fazer uploads através de Jquery